# Change calculator only works if one type of coin needed

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm currently trying to learn python and have been going through beginner projects on /r/learnpython. My idea for the change calculator project was to create a dictionary with keys 'quarter', 'dime', 'nickel', and 'penny', each with values initialized to 0. My code, shown below, appears to only work when the change I input only requires one type of coin, i.e. 0.75 --> 3 quarters, 0.1 --> 1 dime, etc.

```
 change_map = {
    'quarter' : 0,
    'dime' : 0,
    'nickel' : 0,
    'penny' : 0
}

def calculator(change):
    while change > 0:
        if change >= 0.25:
            change -= 0.25
            change_map['quarter'] += 1
        elif change < 0.25 and change >= 0.10:
            change -= 0.10
            change_map['dime'] += 1
        elif change < 0.10 and change >= 0.05:
            change -= 0.05
            change_map['nickel'] += 1
        elif change < 0.05 and change >= 0.01:
            change -= 0.01
            change_map['penny'] += 1
    print "You need the following: "
    print change_map

change = raw_input("Please enter amount of change: ")
change = float(change)
calculator(change)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Floating point arithmetic error

Your error is due to [float arithmetic error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken). Here is what happens when you input a value such as `0.26`.

```
change = 0.26
change  -= 0.25
change  -= 0.01
print (change) # 8.673617379884035e-18
```

Since the last value of `change` is above `0` but below `0.01`, you enter an infinite loop.

## How to fix it

One way to fix this is to rely on exact arithmetic by using `int` instead of `float` to represent discrete values such as currencies. This means making your base unit the cent instead of the dollar.

```
change_map = {
    'quarter' : 0,
    'dime' : 0,
    'nickel' : 0,
    'penny' : 0
}

def calculator(change):
    while change > 0:
        if change >= 25:
            change -= 25
            change_map['quarter'] += 1
        elif change >= 10:
            change -= 10
            change_map['dime'] += 1
        elif change >= 5:
            change -= 5
            change_map['nickel'] += 1
        else:
            change -= 1
            change_map['penny'] += 1

    print ("You need the following: ")
    print (change_map)

change = raw_input("Please enter amount of change: ")

# Here we convert the decimal value input by the user to cents
change = int(float(change) * 100)

calculator(change)
```

Example:

```
Please enter amount of change: 0.26
You need the following: 
{'quarter': 1, 'dime': 0, 'nickel': 0, 'penny': 1}
```

## Improvements

On a side note, you can improve your solution by using a `dict` of values and names for coins. In particular, this allows you to extend your program by updating the `dict` instead of having to add a new if-statement.

Here is an example that adds in the possibility to return a dollar as change.

```
value_map = {
    100: 'dollar',
    25: 'quarter',
    10: 'dime',
    5: 'nickel',
    1: 'penny'
}

def calculator(change):
    change_map = {}

    for value in sorted(value_map, reverse=True):
        coin = value_map[value]
        change_map[coin], change = divmod(change, value)

    print ("You need the following: ")
    print (change_map)

change = raw_input("Please enter amount of change: ")

change = int(float(change) * 100)

calculator(change)
```

Comment: To add to this you are running into an infinite loop since float stores values as "0.00000000002" and your program doesnt have an else statement. Adding else:break to your code allows you to run 0.76 and other values

Comment: Thank you for the help! That was very insightful

Answer (score 2):

I debugged your code and noticed that there was an infinite loop. Probably, that because of float arithmetics. You can declare an epsilon value like

```
eps = 1e-2
```

And change the while loop respectively

```
while change > eps
```

Comment: This can still potentially break on very long chain of operation. If you are allowed arbitrarly many operations, you can make the float error arbitrarly big.

Comment: @OlivierMelançon this doesn't make sense because he doesn't have proper "coins" to increase an error much

Comment: @Kirial Korolev here is an example of what I mean. `x = 1000.01; while x > 0: x -= 0.25` The final output is `-0.2400000000000091`. Now make x larger.  `x = 10000.01; while x > 0: x -= 0.25`, the final output is now `-0.23999999999978172`. Thus by making the initial value bigger, the error grows. In particular, I  could make the error grow above the bound you gave in your answer by choosing a big enough x.